# JQuery multiple selectors, "AND" operator

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The followingcode will fire alert to the click event for elements with Class = `a.cssPauseAll` `OR` attribute = `historyID`

```
$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll,[historyID]", function () {
    alert($(this));

});
```

How can I use multiple selectors using an `AND` operator?

which means, the elements with the `a.cssPauseAll` class `AND` `historyID` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the `,` from your selector:

```
$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[historyID]", function () {
```

`historyID` is not a valid attribute you can use `data-*` attribute instead:

```
$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[data-historyid]", function () {
```

Comment: I don't get it.. is data- just a convention? because it works without it

Comment: @EdwinSoho Yes, it works, but makes your document invalid, `data-*` attributes allow you to store custom data in your document http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

> the elements with the *a.cssPauseAll* class AND *historyID* attribute

Use the following selector:

```
a.cssPauseAll[historyID]
```

Test it yourself - http://jsfiddle.net/SrNDt/

**Note:** Commas separate selectors and therefore behave as a logical `OR`. *Chaining* expressions into a single selector behave as a logical `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click","a.cssPauseAll[historyID]", function () {
```

Just remove the **comma,**